# How do I add an exception to my route file for some vanity names when using the Vanity gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I am using the Vanity gem that handles all `params[:vname]` in my URLs and redirects to the right place for most `vnames`.

But I just added authentication via Omnipopulus - https://github.com/icelab/omnipopulus - and it requires me to go to `mydomain.com/login'.

But when I do that it sends it to my `Vanities` controller. Here is the log of that request:

```
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-18 16:39:15 -0500
  Processing by VanitiesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"vname"=>"login"}
  Vanity Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "vanities".* FROM "vanities" WHERE "vanities"."name" = 'login' LIMIT 1
Rendered public/404.html within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 13ms (Views: 11.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

What the `Vanities` controller does, is when it gets a URL as `mydomain.com/vname` it checks to see if a `vname` record exists for the value in the params (which is typically a username). If it finds one, it redirects to the show action of that user. But given that `login` is not a user nor username, it shouldn't be handling the routing for that keyword.

How do I add an exception?

This is the route for the `Vanities` controller:

```
 controller :vanities do 
    match ':vname' => :show, :via => :get, :constraints => {:vname => /@?[A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+/}, :as => :vanity
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used (or even heard of) this gem before, but looking at its source code, see:
https://github.com/icelab/omnipopulus/blob/master/config/routes.rb

This appears to install itself as a Rails engine, and therefore isn't really in your routes.rb file.  I'm thinking there may be a few things to test here.

First of all, realize that vanities' routes MUST be the ABSOLUTE DEAD LAST in your routes file.  What's happening here is that when you call /login, the vanities routing is happening before your authentication gem's routing is being called.  Normally I'd just say, "move the vanities routes to the last in routes.rb", but given that omnipopulous injects its routes based on its engine, that may not be enough.

I see two possible ways of solving this:

1. Check out Gemfile and make sure that Vanities is loaded AFTER omnipopulous.
2. If that fails, copy the routes in the link I posted above into routes.rb BEFORE the vanities routes.

I see #2 as an ugly hack, so I really hope #1 works first (depends on load order for gems with bundler, which I think will go top-down, but I don't have any proof of that so far).

Comment: The vanities route is absolutely dead last. I moved the gem call after omnipopulous and did `bundle update` but that doesn't seem to work. I will try copying the route to the routes file and see. I have also asked the gem author if the engine is supposed to put a route in my `routes.rb` file because as is it doesn't.

Comment: It seems copying the route from the github repo to my `routes.rb` works. Thanks!